# PE - IAT resolve mechanism

Tags: pe, iat

I'm trying to understand how Windows is resolving functions with the IAT.

I have noticed that when a call is made to a Win API function, the structure of that call is not always the same (it's still consistent inside a binary, but not between two differents binary).

Sometime, if i follow the target address of that call, i find a jump to the resolved Win API function.
And sometime, it's directly a call to the resolved function.

For instance:

- the binary A is using call like :
  `call    ds:GetSystemDirectoryW`
- the binary B is calling like that:
  `call  GetSystemDirectoryW  -> jmp ds:__imp_GetSystemDirectoryW`

Can someone explain me the this difference in the calling procedure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct call can be generated by the compiler when it knows that the function comes from a DLL at compile time, or whole program optimization is used. If the target function is not marked as dllimport, the compiler generates a simple call to an external symbol and at link time this external symbol is  resolved to a stub which actually jumps to the DLL import.
For more info:

[Importing function calls using __declspec(dllimport)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-function-calls-using-declspec-dllimport)

[What is DLL import binding?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100318-00/?p=14563)